# JQuery and Internet Explorer - JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a little script that replaces text with images depending on the value in a Wordpress custom field. It works perfectly fine in all browsers apart from IE.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.CustomRow').each(function(i, e) {
    if (m = (text = $(e).text().trim()).match(re = /: +(yes|no)$/)) {
        var class = $('span', e).text().replace(/[^\w]/g, '').toLowerCase();
        $(e)
            .addClass(class)
//              .text(text.replace(re, ''))
        ;
    }

});
if ($('.levelparking').html().match(/yes/)) {
    $('.levelparking').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/level_ground.jpg">');
} else {
    $('.levelparking').hide();
    }

if ($('.water').html().match(/yes/)) {
    $('.water').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/water.jpg">');
}else {
    $('.water').hide();
    }

 if ($('.greywater').html().match(/yes/)) {
    $('.greywater').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/grey_water.jpg">');
}else {
    $('.greywater').hide();
    }

 if ($('.blackwater').html().match(/yes/)) {
    $('.blackwater').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/black_water.jpg">');
}else {
    $('.blackwater').hide();
    }

 if ($('.electric').html().match(/yes/)) {
    $('.electric').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/electricity.jpg">');
}else {
    $('.electric').hide();
    }

if ($('.extranight').html().match(/yes/)) {
    $('.extranight').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/xtra_night.jpg">');
}else {
    $('.extranight').hide();
    }

if ($('.dogwalks').html().match(/yes/)) {
    $('.dogwalks').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/dog_walks.jpg">');
}else {
    $('.dogwalks').hide();
    }

if ($('.realales').html().match(/yes/)) {
    $('.realales').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/real_ales.jpg">');
}else {
    $('.realales').hide();
    }

    if ($('.busstop').html().match(/yes/)) {
    $('.busstop').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/bus_stop.jpg">');
}else {
    $('.busstop').hide();
    }

    if ($('.wifi').html().match(/yes/)) {
    $('.wifi').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/directorypress/thumbs/wifi.jpg">');
}else {
    $('.wifi').hide();
    }


});
```

I'm getting the following error message in IE Developer Tools:

Expected Identifier - Line 4, character 17.

This relates to this line:

```
var class = $('span', e).text().replace(/[^\w]/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? Sometimes a simple version update resolves some IE bugs(I just resolved one last week upgrading from 1.3.2 to 1.5). And I never believe at IE line numbers, it dont show which file this line belongs

Comment: Side note: The regular expression `/[^\w]/g` can be written as simply `/\W/g`. Even better use `/\W+/g` so that it replaces chunks of characters instead of one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

`"var class"` is most likely the problem because `class` is a reserved keyword in IE.

The solution is to use another variable name.

Comment: I've used another variable name but am still getting the same error plus another - Object doesn't support this property or method - line 3 character 9

Comment: Ok that's good, it just means there are several errors in the snipplet and you just got rid of the first one, therefore you may want to check out the suggestions from Aliostad and cjstehno as well.

Answer (score 3):

`class` is a [reserved keyword](http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/ecmascript/reserved-words/) in Javascript (ECMAScript), use a different variable name.

The reason that it works in some browsers is that they allow some keywords as identifiers in some situations. Naturally you should not use keywords as identifiers at all.

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be on the regular expression. You may want to dig into IE's regular expression support and make sure that it is not slightly different from the other browsers... as is often the case with IE.

Answer (score 0):

`$('span', e)` is null hence it will not work,. Post HTML or a jsfiddle sample.